# I just want to connect the all the minima points as indicated so i get a curved plot

Tags: python, minima

I just want to connect the all the minima points as indicated so i get a curved plot as shown in yellow using the red dots. Can someone help me?

Comment: As indicated by what?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.